# AngularJS Custom Directive similar to ng-requried

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have spent about 4 hours on this already.

What I am trying to achieve is a custom directive that is similar to ng-required which has an input and does the validation. 

Following is the ng-required code.

```
var requiredDirective = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      attr.required = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

      ctrl.$validators.required = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return !attr.required || !ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue);
      };

      attr.$observe('required', function() {
        ctrl.$validate();
      });
    }
  };
};
```

I know when the required attribute changes it's value, we will do validation again. Say if you have

```
<input 
ng-model="sor.seal"
ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
class="form-control" 
ng-required="sor.sealUwatType=='SEAL'" 
type="text"
placeholder="Enter a SEAL/UWAT ID"
id="seal" 
name="seal" 
/>
```

How does it add an attribute *required="required"* when the ng-required expression is true?
And How does it remove the attribute when the ng-required expression is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular creates an internal [ng-attribute Alias directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/33f7f26558a52124c2eaf40d91bedb58686bde0a/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L353) on all the *boolean attribute equivalents* like `ng-required, ng-checked, ng-disabled` etc...

**[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/43769fb676ae904852582a2c88a5523f0b9f58fc/src/jqLite.js#L535)**

```
var BOOLEAN_ATTR = {};
forEach('multiple,selected,checked,disabled,readOnly,required,open'.split(','), function(value) {
  BOOLEAN_ATTR[lowercase(value)] = value;
});
```

and the generic link function registered on these performs a generic toggling of attributes

**[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/33f7f26558a52124c2eaf40d91bedb58686bde0a/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L356)**

```
forEach(BOOLEAN_ATTR, function(propName, attrName) {
  // binding to multiple is not supported
  if (propName == "multiple") return;

  function defaultLinkFn(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr[normalized], function ngBooleanAttrWatchAction(value) {
      attr.$set(attrName, !!value);
    });
  }

  var normalized = directiveNormalize('ng-' + attrName);
  var linkFn = defaultLinkFn;

  if (propName === 'checked') {
    linkFn = function(scope, element, attr) {
      // ensuring ngChecked doesn't interfere with ngModel when both are set on the same input
      if (attr.ngModel !== attr[normalized]) {
        defaultLinkFn(scope, element, attr);
      }
    };
  }

  ngAttributeAliasDirectives[normalized] = function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 100,
      link: linkFn
    };
  };
});
```

So basically `ng-required` adds the attribute `required` [which itself is registered internally as a directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/39b634e50a9ed140649d4be119a291debe527d55/src/AngularPublic.js#L199) that does the [validation for `ng-model`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0e001084ffff8674efad289d37cb16cc4e46b50a/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L3).

You can verify this by outputting what `ngRequired` directive actually holds, it holds 2 directive configurations, one with priority 100 (which runs before ng-model), which sets/resets the attribute on the element it is upon and another one which has the validation hook with the ng-model and validators.

```
.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('ngRequiredDirective', function($delegate) {
    console.log($delegate); //Check the console on the configuration you will see array of 2 configurations
    return $delegate;
  })
});
```

This is as good as creating 2 configurations for same directive selector, example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function() {
      console.log("A");
    }
  }
}).directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function() {
      console.log("B");
    }
  }
}).config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('myDirDirective', function($delegate) {
    console.log($delegate); //Check the console on the configuration you will see array of 2 configurations
    return $delegate;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

  <div my-dir></div>
</div>
```