# AngularJS - What is expected behaviour of two directives with the same name but in different modules?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Of course, I can check it myself.
It's more conceptual/architectural question and why it was build so.

```
angular.module('appmodule1').directive('mydir', function(){});

angular.module('appmodule2').directive('mydir', function(){});
```

so what should we expect from `mydir`?

**UPD**: 
dependencies between the modules:

```
angular.module('app',['appmodule1', 'appmodule2'])
```

or

```
angular.module('appmodule1', ['appmodule2']);
```

Comment: I think this will all depend on what your directives are actually doing. They could build off of each other or conflict tragically. http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/tip-directives-with-the-same-name/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trivial thing is that if your module only directly/indirectly loads only one of the module then that directive factory only will be used. But if your question is what if both the modules are loaded say for example `angular.module('app',['appmodule1', 'appmodule2'])` and your application is bootstrapped with the module `app` then the directive factories will be added together, i.e directive factories are additive and such component when used will render with both the factories.

```js
angular.module('app1', []).directive('mydir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function() {
      console.log("App1");
    }
  }
});

angular.module('app2', []).directive('mydir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function() {
      console.log("App2");
    }
  }
});;
angular.module('app', ['app1', 'app2']).config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('ngRequiredDirective', function($delegate) {
    console.log($delegate); //Check the console on the configuration you will see array of 2 configurations
    return $delegate;
  })
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <mydir></mydir>
  <test ng-required="true"></test>
</div>
```

Generally the scoping, template etc cannot be specified in both (*Rules are same  as when an element has more than one directives mentioned*) and these kind of directives are generally defined in the same module (or even in a different module) with intend and for special purpose. For example angular internally has a directive with the selector `select` which works along with `ng-options` directive, now say in your application you want to convert all the `select` to a bootstrap select option or with ng-repeated material select. You can abstract them out an still create another directive with the selector `select` and add your logic to render it by parsing the `ng-options` expression and render the new dropdown.

An example is within angular itself,  the way `ng-required` and other similar directives are implemented, [see this answer for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406139/angularjs-custom-directive-similar-to-ng-requried/32406371#32406371). You can check it out by doing a console log of `ng-required` directive factory as below.

```
.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('ngRequiredDirective', function($delegate) {
    console.log($delegate); //Check the console on the configuration you will see array of 2 configurations
    return $delegate;
  })
});
```

> Why it was built?

By bet would be on extensibility and dividing different responsibility in different factories.

So in short if at all you have multiple directive factories for the same selector it should not be accidental, but created with clear purpose, otherwise it could turn out to be a disaster!

Comment: if scope isolated in both things fall apart for duplicate isolated scopes on same element

Comment: @charlietfl ofcourse, that is trivial, and this is created with intend, for example ng-required directive

Comment: in first code snippet it should be decorator('mydir' ... , right?

Comment: @STEVER i added only to show ngrequired directive factories, if you use `decorator('mydirDirective',...` you will see 2 configurations for that as well. You need to postfix it with the word "Directive" in the decorator because factories are created that way for the directives internally. But generally if you the other answer of mine it should have an explanation of purpose and implementation of ng-required directive with multiple factories. Hope i explained stuffs clearly enough with the best of my understanding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It will depend under which module the directive is instantiated. If you're under the appmodule1, the corresponding directive would be used. There would be no conflict here, unless I'm missing something.